# Camera rotates 7 times around its axis THREE.JS GSAP

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera, gsap, scrolltrigger

Im making online gallery and I need to move camera on scroll.

The problem is when I trying to rotate it by Y axis its rotate 3 times around its axis and thats wrong!

Im trying do somthing similar like this `https://virtual.plus-ex.com/showroom`
when you enter easy mode, camera moves and rotate automaticly.

Here's my pen `https://codepen.io/lucas23456/pen/jOzpVYd`

When trigger 4 passed it should look at wall with pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're allowing the rotation range to be from `[-100, 100]` when adding the GUI:

```
cameraFolder.add(camera.rotation, 'y', -100, 100)
```

Keep mind that [Euler rotations are in radians](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.rotation), not in degrees, so there is a big difference. Going from 0-100 radians will actually spin the camera about 15 times!

| Degrees | Radians |
| --- | --- |
| 360° | Math.PI * 2 = ~6.28 |
| 180° | Math.PI = ~3.14 |
| 90° | Math.PI / 2 = ~1.57 |

You'll have to convert from degrees to radians with a simple equation:

```
camera.rotation.y = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
```